I'm trying to visualize a table of numbers in square grids. Square numbers specifically
I've generated a table of the first 30 square numbers in Mathematica.
I want each number in the table to generate it's own image. For example, the second number in the list is 4, so I'd like to generate a pictures of 4 individual squares which themselves make an image of a square composed of 4 squares.
Context: My 3 year old loves the TV show Number Blocks. He's particularly fond of square numbers. He asks me what the bigger square numbers look like so I'd like to generate the images for him to look at.
Thanks.

Something like this? Table[Grid[Partition[Range[n^2], n], Frame -> All], {n, Range[10]}]

Thats perfect, thank you!
